# How to create a search function for numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to learning Python and am wondering if I would be able to create a function which would allow me to choose a specific artist or genre and it would return all instances of this artist/genre. Thank you

```
import numpy as np
choice = input("Do you want to add an album?(yes/no)")
arr2 = np.array(["Artist", "Album", "Format", "Genre"])
while choice == "yes":
    artist = input("Input artist")
    album = input("Input album name")
    format = input("Input format")
    genre = input("Input genre")
    newarr = np.array([artist, album, format, genre])
    arr2 = np.vstack(((arr2, newarr)))
    print(arr2)

    print("Do you want to add another record?")
    addAnother = input()
    if addAnother == "no":
        print("No problem. This is your finished collection")
        print(arr2)
        break


else:
    print("Ok")
```

Comment: What is the problem? You have a bunch of code, and you ask if something is possible. Does the code not work? Are you asking something else? Could you clarify what your expectation is?

Comment: I can input artist,album,genre and format and add them to the array but i dont know how i would start to write a search function. Thank you

Comment: first use `input()` to get searched value. Later use this value to compare with row. ie. `newarr[ newarr[0] == "Madonna" ]` But frankly I would rather use `pandas.DataFrame` instead of `numpy.array`

Comment: Ok thank you I will add that at the end as an option after they have finished inputting all instances

Comment: BTW: maybe first create some data directly in code (without using `input()`) to fast test searching code.

Answer (score 0):

First you should create some data in code to test searching function without adding artist again and again.

---

To search by artists

```
arr[ arr[:,0] == 'Madonna' ]
```

To search by album

```
arr[ arr[:,0] == 'Virgin' ]
```

etc.

---

Minimal working code

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.asarray([
    ['Artist', 'Album', 'Format', 'Genre'],
    ['Madonna', 'Virgin', 'CD', 'POP'],
    ['Jacson', 'Thriller', 'CD', 'POP'],
    ['Other', 'Noname', 'Cassette', 'POP'],
])

print('--- by artist ---')
#user_input = input('Artist: ')
user_input = 'Madonna'
print(arr[ arr[:,0] == user_input ])

print('--- by format ---')
#user_input = input('Foramt: ')
user_input = 'CD'
print(arr[ arr[:,2] == user_input ])
```

---

**EDIT:**

Using `pandas` seems for me more readable and more useful. You can use column name instead column number, you can save in CSV file and read again from CSV file.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['Madonna', 'Virgin', 'CD', 'POP'],
        ['Jacson', 'Thriller', 'CD', 'POP'],
        ['Other', 'Noname', 'Cassette', 'POP'],
    ],
    columns=['Artist', 'Album', 'Format', 'Genre'],
)

print('--- all data ---')
print(df)

print('--- by artist ---')
#user_input = input('Artist: ')
user_input = 'Madonna'

print(df[ df['Artist'] == user_input ])

print('--- by format ---')
#user_input = input('Format: ')
user_input = 'CD'

print(df[ df['Format'] == user_input ])
```

You can also use `lower()` to compare it in different cases

```
user_input = 'Madonna'

print(df[ df['Artist'].str.lower() == user_input.lower() ])
```

You can search partial text

```
user_input = 'Mad'

print(df[ df['Artist'].str.contains(user_input) ])
```

And both

```
print(df[ df['Artist'].str.lower().str.contains(user_input.lower()) ])
```